# Saving all items from 2 listboxes to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to take all the items from a list box and save them into separated fields into a SQL Server database. The user pushes a save button and I would like for all of the items in the list box to be separated into their appropriate fields and saved into said fields in the SQL Server database. The items start out separated in a DGVgrid and are combined when the enter the List box. What is the best way to go about this? The SQL Server database has the same columns and the DGVgrid.

I am using VB in Visual Studio and a SQL Server database that I have created on my machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a bit and I'm not sure where to go from here.

I think that the problem may be the List boxes because I have been able to save to my SQL Server database when the data comes from Text boxes, but I do not want to get rid of the List boxes. I have tried changes the List boxes out with DGVgridview boxes, but this did not work. I could not get the items to neatly go into the columns that they needed to. Would I be better of just trying to save the data into a Text file?

```vb
   Public Function InStrRev(StringCheck As String, StringMatch As String, Optional Start As Integer = -1, Optional Compare As CompareMethod = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary) As Integer

    End Function
    Public Function InStr(Start As Integer, String1 As String, String2 As String, Optional Compare As CompareMethod = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary) As Integer

    End Function
    Public Function Mid(Str As String, Start As Integer, Length As Integer) As String
    End Function

  Static IntStart As Integer
        Dim Backpack1 = BP1ListBox.ToString()
        Dim Backpack2 = BP2ListBox.ToString()
        Dim user As String = ReturningUser.UserNametxt.Text
        Dim con As SqlConnection
        Dim deletecmd As SqlCommand
        Dim objcmd As SqlCommand
        Dim deletereader As SqlDataReader
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim BackpackName As String
        Dim item As String
        Dim weightposition As Integer
        Dim weight As String
        Dim username As String = CStr(ReturningUser.UserNametxt.Text)
        Dim delete As String = "Delete From UserBackpackItems where UserName = '" & username & "'"
        Dim stmt As String = "Insert Into UserBackpackItems(UserName, BackpackName, Item, Weight,) Values('" & username & "', '" & BackpackName & "', '" & ItemNametxt.Text & "', '" & ItemWeighttxt.Text & "')"
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-AUS1VBC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BackpackDatabase;Integrated Security=True")
        con.Open()

        'delete previous save
        deletecmd = New SqlCommand(delete, con)
        deletereader = deletecmd.ExecuteReader()

        'create a new save
        For Counter = IntStart To BP1ListBox.Items.Count - 1
            Dim ListItems As String = BP1ListBox.Items.ToString
            item = Mid(ListItems(Counter), 1, InStr(1, ListItems(Counter), "  ", CompareMethod.Text))
            weightposition = InStrRev(ListItems(Counter), "  ", CompareMethod.Text)
            weight = Mid(ListItems(Counter), weightposition, Length:=BP1ListBox.Items(Counter))
            objcmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(stmt, con)
            reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader()

        Next
```

Comment: Why are you deleting a user and then adding the same user back again?

Comment: Is `BP1ListBox` the name of a ListBox?

Comment: BP1 is the items. I wanted to be able to have the previous save deleted and the new save to be the only data.

Comment: I was able to figure to out by putting it under another command where the data is in text boxes and not list boxes.

Comment: Are you aware that there is such a thing as an Update command for Sql? It is meant to change data in an existing record.

Comment: I clearly asked if BPListBox is the Name of a ListBox. Please answer that question. I am glad you got it working but don't you have any curiosity why your first attempt doesn't work?